# How to add a reset button to clear numbers on Edittext field

Tags: java, android

I want to add a button to clear the numbers on textfield by tapping on the button.

(Reset my EditText back to an empty "space" after a button has pressed that would have completed an activity with input from the EditText field.)

Cheers! Thanks!

ActivityMain XML file!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.miuapps.unitconverter.Centimetres_Metres" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"    //first textview
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter a Value(cm) :"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay1"   //output textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Metres: 0"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
double counter, counter2 = 100;
    double x;
    Button conv;
    TextView dis1, dis2;
    EditText ent1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;

        conv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        dis1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay1);
        //dis2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay2);
        ent1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        conv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                x = new Integer(ent1.getText().toString());
                counter = x/100;
                //counter2++;
                dis1.setText("In Metres: " +counter);
                //dis2.setText("In Centimetres: " +counter2);
            }
    });  
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your editText of inputType numbers? Or you want to filter numbers and remove them? Or just remove all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
ent1.setText("");
```

just put it at the end of your onClick Method

**Edit:**

```
conv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // here you get the text from your editText
                x = new Integer(ent1.getText().toString());

                // do something with the text
                counter = x/100;

                // set result in another TextView
                dis1.setText("In Metres: " +counter);

                // work is done, so the editText can be cleared
                ent1.setText("");

            }
    });
```

**Edit 2 (reset button):**

```
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // reset only by another button
                ent1.setText("");

            }
    });
```

Comment: after adding that line its clearing just tap on the convert button

Comment: You ask for clear when tapping the button, the conversion should be displayd in the textView already, so the EditText can be cleared?!

Comment: please can you put the code here by adding that code! um not a genius on coding

Comment: yea i did like that! bt its clearing automatically when um tapped on activity button(convert button). i want to keep the text after the activity and i want to clear it by another button named reset!

Comment: ah, thats a different way. i will add it... You only showed one button. Of course you have to use the onClickListener of the reset button to clear th edit text then

Comment: ahha that means i have to create another onClickListener method! can you tell me how to do that?? thanks lot for your help!! :)

Comment: same way you created the first. just with the other button variable. Of course you have to add another button into your layout

Comment: okay it worked! bt after resetting  when i gave another value and i tapped on convert button its getting stopped the application. why is that?

Comment: i think this is now another question, which i cant answer without the actual code and the error message.  Please accept this answer here and create a new question if you need

Comment: ahhaa k it working now! i edited the code as ent1.setText(null); now its working like charm!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a button in your layout.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

Find that button in your activity:

```
Button mButtonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);
mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        ent1.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **First Create Design,**

[image]

**Activity_main.xml like below,**

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cln"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Clear" />
```

2. **Then go to MainActivity.java edit code like below, **

**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button,button2;
    EditText editText;
    String name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_cln);
        //create text add button
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name = editText.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        //clean,reset text button
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**